# Mapinfo Layout WIndow

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have to create multiple maps using the same layout, but different map views (more than 100 maps).  There is a separate rectangles layer created for each view at a specific scale using the map frame from the layout window. Within the layout window, I would like to automate the process by updating automatically attribute information for layers displayed within the map frame within text boxes on the layout.

Is there any possibility to do this process through a MapBasic script? As far I have researched the topic, I didn't find any solution. Also, I know that Mapinfo 15.2 has the capability to support multiple pages layouts, but the amount of information that needs to be displayed increases the resources usage, which make the program run really really slow.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something like data-driven pages. Take a look this tool by John Wilcock, might do the job for you (not sure if it's been tested on versions later than 12 though) - http://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/code-exchange/download/data-driven-pages/

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.  As per description, it looks like a useful tool. I've downloaded it and tried to run the .mbx file on Mapinfo 15.2 and the tool starts the process of creating the layout window and it gives an error half way through, with a message suggesting that some .xml files are missing.

Comment: Have you got .NET framework 4.0 installed? If not, that could be the issue, otherwise it might just be an issue with the version of MapInfo.

Comment: That was the next step I took. I tried to install the .net framework 4 and a message showed up on the installer saying that it is already installed.

Comment: I know there have been significant changes in the way the layout windows are implemented in later versions so that may be where the tool is failing. Might be worth searching around to see if there's anything similar for v12.5+ available.  Failing that, if you have any skill in MapBasic you could look at updating the tool to work for later versions as the source code is all available on [GitHub](https://github.com/JohnWilcock/MapInfoDataDrivenPages/).

Comment: Yeah, the Data Driven Pages tool was written for the 32-bit version of MapInfo Pro and will probably not work on the latest 64-bit version

Comment: From reading your question I can decipher three questions: 1. Zoom and Center a map using Frames in a table. 2. Replacing texts in the layout with texts from a table 3. Complex label expressions. Maybe you should consider splitting this question into 3

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question, and since you seem to be asking for help with code you should also include a code snippet to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. At the time when this query was posted, I didn't have any solutions at all or any code available. Recently, I have managed to build up a code for a toolbar that I can use to update the layout using pre-selected tables, by creating text boxes on the layout. I was not familiar with Tour link recommended, but I will keep in mind for future queries.

Comment: @IoanaMuresan, if you want to share your tool with the MapInfo Community, you can share it on the Community Download page: http://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/. Whether you want to share it or not, is entirely up to you